# else php not working in search condicion

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a litle aplication for rental cars in php.

### My problem is condicion of if, elseif e else, because else downt working.

```
<?php
if (empty($busca)) {
echo 'Coloque uma palavra-chave para podermos procurar o seu carro.<br>';
}
elseif ($busca= 'empty' OR $sql == 0) {
echo 'Nao encontramos valores na nossa base de dados.<br>';
}
else{
echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" bgcolor=\"#000033\">
<tr bgcolor=\"#0066FF\">
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Marca</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Modelo</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Classe</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Matricula</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Ver</font></b></th>
</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result))
{
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#0066FF\">";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['marca'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['modelo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['classe'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['matricula'] . "</td>";
echo ("<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><a href=\"http://localhost/autorental/index.php?pagina=veiculo&matricula=$row[matricula]\">Ver</a></td>");
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change the line

```
elseif ($busca= 'empty' OR $sql == 0) {
```

into

```
elseif ($busca == 'empty' OR $sql == 0) {
```

Right now you are assigning 'empty' to the variable $busca, but what you want is a comparison. With your current code, 'empty' will be assigned to $busca and the assign-statement then returns a true. Therefore, the elseif-block will always return true and the else-block will never be reached.

For checking for empty return set from the database, I'd recommend the following:

```
if (empty($busca)) {
    echo 'Coloque uma palavra-chave para podermos procurar o seu carro.<br/>';
} elseif (mysqli_num_rows($rs_result) == 0) {
    echo 'Nao encontramos valores na nossa base de dados.<br>';
} else {
    echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" bgcolor=\"#000033\">
    <tr bgcolor=\"#0066FF\">
    <th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Marca</font></b></th>
    <th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Modelo</font></b></th>
    <th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Classe</font></b></th>
    <th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Matricula</font></b></th>
    <th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Ver</font></b></th>
    </tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result))
    {
        echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#0066FF\">";
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['marca'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['modelo'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['classe'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['matricula'] . "</td>";
        echo ("<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><a href=\"http://localhost/autorental/index.php?pagina=veiculo&matricula=$row[matricula]\">Ver</a></td>");
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: I meant only that when the search returns values ​​from the data base informs the user. 
Any idea?

Comment: Let me know whether it works, respectively what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `||` instead of `OR`

Also you have used one `=` which is used for assignment in PHP however using `==` is used as a comparision operator

here is how:

```
<?php
if(empty($busca)) {
echo 'Coloque uma palavra-chave para podermos procurar o seu carro.<br>';
}
elseif($busca == 'empty' || $sql == 0) {
echo 'Nao encontramos valores na nossa base de dados.<br>';
} else{
echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" bgcolor=\"#000033\">
<tr bgcolor=\"#0066FF\">
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Marca</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Modelo</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Classe</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Matricula</font></b></th>
<th><b><font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Ver</font></b></th>
</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result))
{
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#0066FF\">";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['marca'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['modelo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['classe'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">" . $row['matricula'] . "</td>";
echo ("<td bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"><a href=\"http://localhost/autorental/index.php?pagina=veiculo&matricula=$row[matricula]\">Ver</a></td>");
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
?>
```